# How to use Parse Cloud to get one user to follow another?

Tags: android, parse-platform

For my Android application, I want to make possible that a user follows another user. So I added a relation column for the users which will contains the following users.

Here is my parse cloud function. I'm just trying to add the `currentUser` to the followers relation of the user he wants to follow.

```
Parse.Cloud.define('sabonner', function(request, response) {
var userId = request.params.userId;

var User = Parse.Object.extend('_User');
    user = new User({ objectId: userId });

var currentUser = request.user;

var relation = user.relation("abonnesRelation");
relation.add(currentUser);

Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
user.save().then(function(user) {
    response.success(user);
}, function(error) {
    response.error(error)
});
});
```

Here is how I call it:

```
String targetId=mUsers.get(position).getObjectId();
HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            params.put("userId",targetId );
            ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("sabonner", params,
new FunctionCallback<String>() {
                public void done(String result, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        Log.d("ParseCloud", "successs :"+result);
                    } else {
                        Log.d("ParseCloud", "unsuccesss :" + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }

            });
```

For now I'm having this error:

> parsecloud java.lang.ClassCastException: com.parse.ParseUser cannot be cast to String.

It's my first use of Parse Cloud so I'm sure that there there are many things to modify here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like in `functionCallback` you're receiving ParseUser not String.

Just try to change your callback as follows:

```
ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("sabonner", params, new FunctionCallback<ParseUser>() {
            public void done(ParseUser result, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Log.d("ParseCloud", "successs :"+result);
                } else {
                    Log.d("ParseCloud", "unsuccesss :" + e.getMessage());
                }
            }

        });
```

Comment: thank you Oleg, but i till having some difficulties to retrieve user from his id..

Comment: you need to get ParseUser by some id?

Comment: yes: i need to retrieve two users, the follower and the user being followed: the follower i'm retrieving it by var currentUser = request.user; the one being followed i'm first getting his id by var userId = request.params.userId; and then user = new User({ objectId: userId });

Comment: the var userId = request.params.userId; is working fine. I now till need to retreve the other one from the id passed with the request